# can I use a typedef in @cython.locals

Tags: cython

foo.pxd:

```
cdef class cls: pass
ctypedef int typ
```

main.pxd:

```
from foo cimport cls, typ
```

main.pyx:

```
import cython

@cython.locals(a='cls')
def f(a): pass

@cython.locals(b='typ') # doesn't compile
def g(b): pass
```

Cython compiles function f() but not function g(), saying 'Not a type.'
If I remove the quotes from 'typ' then it will compile, but no longer run in the interpreter.
It's important to me that any solution works compiled AND interpreted.

Comment: This does look like something that should work. I'd check the most recent version of Cython that you can find, and report it on the Cython bug tracker

Comment: @ead No - but I think OP is only trying to use it as a function argument. It's the equivalent of `def g(int b)` which should be valid